# Custom rating bar

Tags: android, ratingbar

i have three custom images for stars in my rating bar

[image] [image] [image]

**Layer list (rating_bar_bronze)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rating_empty"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rating_half_bronze"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rating_full_bronze"/>

</layer-list>
```

**Rating bar in xml**

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBarNearby"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvProfileSkill"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivProfilePhoto"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rating_bar_bronze" />
```

But my rating bar always shows only one star that is cropped, as in the picture below
[image]

Comment: try adding stepsize. android:stepSize="1"

Comment: it looks different ... but what effect does stepSize have on ratingbar style ? :)

Comment: Not sure. I thought it would have been important attribute to specify :)

Comment: I had it defined programatically to 0.01f :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I think I may be having a similar issue, where it will only show one star, and only the `@android:id/progress` item's drawable. My code is here: https://gist.github.com/shekibobo/4d303a595aa2367b6311

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will be useful for you at this point, but I made a custom ratingbar which might help you: [SimpleRatingBar](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar).

It features:

- Fully working `android:layout_width`: it can be set to `wrap_content`, `match_parent` or abritary dp.
- Arbitrary number of stars.
- Arbitrary step size.
- Size of stars can be controlled exactly or by setting a maximum size.
- Customizable colors in normal state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable colors in pressed state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable size separation between stars.
- Customizable border width of stars.
- Customizable stars corner radius.
- Allows to set OnRatingBarChangeListener
- Stars fill can be set to start from left to right or from right to left (RTL language support).
- AnimationBuilder integrated in the view to set rating programatically with animation.

[Here is a preview of it](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar/raw/master/images/sample.gif).

You can find it either in `jcenter` or in `Maven Central`. So in your `build.gradle` file just add to your dependencies:

`compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.+'`

In your example, you can use it as:

```
<com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvProfileSkill"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivProfilePhoto"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
        app:srb_stepSize="0.01"
        app:srb_borderColor="@color/your_bronze_color"
        app:srb_fillColor="@color/your_bronze_color"
        />
```

No extra xml files needed :)

I hope it's useful.